# FCM Android SDK returns invalid tokens

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with Android FCM SDK while obtaining FCM tokens.

Steps:

1. Application gets tokens from Android FCM SDK
2. Few minutes later we are trying send push message to this device
3. We get response from FCM cloud "device_unregistered"
4. After reinstall application, FCM SDK returns new active tokens.

Any suggestions why FCM SDK sometimes returns inactive tokens?

Using SDKs:

com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0

com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1

Greetings,
Krzysztof

Comment: Step 1 already sounds absurd, while this question is way too abstract to answer it.

Comment: I mean Android FCM SDK, sorry ;)

Comment: With no details showing **how** you are trying to do this, it wuold be very difficult to help.